# Formatting figures on a single page without leaving space at the bottom

Tags: spacing, floats

When Using 6 figures in a single page, I am forced to make figures small. But, this arrangement leaves a lot of empty space at the bottom. How to enlarge image without having to move them to different pages?

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx! Please include a MWE that replicates your problem.

Comment: Please indicate how the figures are arranged on the page: Are the six figures placed one above the other, or are there three rows with 2 figures each, or whatever? How much spare vertical whitespace are we talking about anyway: Half a page, one quarter, or something else?

Answer (score 2):

I have a example for multiple figures. Try this code and then modify for your case :

```
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering

    %%----First subfigure----
    \subfigure[]{           
        \includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{../np/im1}}
    hspace{0.1\linewidth}
 %%----second subfigure----
    subfigure[]{        
         \includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{../np/im2}}\\[20pt]

%%----third subfigure----
   subfigure[]{
        \includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{../np/im3}}
    \hspace{0.1\linewidth}

    %%----fouth subfigure----
    \subfigure[]{        
        \includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{../np/im4}}\\[20pt]         
\end{figure}
```